# Exporting SQL Table into a CSV file using Windows Batch Script

Tags: sql, csv, batch-file

I am trying to create a windows batch file to export data from an SQL file to a CSV file.

I have an SQL file in **%MYHOME%\database\NET-DB.sql** which contains data that is:

**NET-DB.sql**

```
insert into net_network (id, a_id, alias, address, domain, mask) values('NET_10.10.1.0_10', 1, 'Local Network', '10.10.1.0', '', '255.255.252.0');
```

What I have tried so far in exporting the data from **net_network** table into a CSV file in my .bat file is with this command:

**export.bat**

```
if not exist "%MYHOME%\net\NUL" mkdir "%MYHOME%\net"
COPY net_network TO '%MYHOME%\net\CSV-EXPORT_FILE.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
pause
```

Since that does not work for me, what should be the correct approach for this implementation? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What size of NET-DB.sql? I think there is a more simple way than bat.

Comment: the sql file has values to be inserted to net_network table. was it done before running `COPY`? what problem you meet btw?..

Comment: you are trying to copy net_network, which is a table inside of SQL to a file, this will not work as batch will never know what net_network is.

Comment: Does not work for you? Did your mouse break? Did your roof fall in? What exactly happened? If there was an error message please post it

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQLCMD`

You need to modify the code to make it work in your environment, but here goes.

```
if not exist "%MYHOME%\net\NUL" mkdir "%MYHOME%\net"
cd "C:\your path\to\sqlcmd"
sqlcmd -S YourDBServer -d DB_NAME -E -Q "select id, a_id, alias, address, domain, mask from net_network" 
       -o "CSV-EXPORT-FILE.csv" -s"," -w 255
```

Some explanations:

`-S` The database server to connect to.

`-d` Name of the database to connect to.

`-Q` Query to run, can also be insert, delete, update etc.

`-o` select the output file

`-s`"," separated by comma

`-w` column width, this has to be as big as your largest columns characters.